# How to access appsettings.json from Azure Service Fabric stateless service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a solution with a stateless service project (.sfproj) and a corresponding console app project.

I have added appsettings.json to the console app project and am trying to set up access to it using this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    //return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners(); //This line works
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[] //This line causes an error in Service Fabric Explorer
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices(
                        services => services
                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    //.UseStartup<Startup>() //Startup.cs does not exist
                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                    .UseUrls(url)
                    .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

This doesn't compile because I don't have a `Startup` class as it's not a web api project, it's using a stateless service. The only classes I have in the console app are `Program.cs`, `Service.cs` and `ServiceEventSource.cs`

I tried removing the `.UseStartup<Startup>()` to get it to compile, however when I run the application, I get the following error in Service Fabric Explorer:

```
'System.FM' reported Error for property 'State'.
Partition is below target replica or instance count.
fabric:/Integration/Integration.Service 1 1 9810816d-5be9-4b53-9eed-c5be403219b0
  InBuild _Node_1 132003711574580709
  (Showing 1 out of 1 instances. Total available instances: 0)
```

I can fix this by using `return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();` instead, however then I don't know how to set up access to appsettings.json.

How can I access `appsettings.json` from within my stateless service?

**EDIT:**

I managed to get it working using this in `Service.cs`:

```
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
```

I added this to `ServiceManifest.xml` to make sure `env.ContentRootPath` points to the code package folder which contains the `appsettings.json` files (the default seems to be the Work folder which was empty for me):

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>TheAppNameGoesHere.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

I added this `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    { }
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way to access `appsettings.json`, especially considering the `Startup.Configure()` method is doing nothing.

Does anyone know a better way to access `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you have to specify the name of the assembly running the app's entry point. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#application-key-name) explain how should be set.

When you use `.UseStartup<Startup>()` it get the assembly information from the `Startup` class, because you don't have one, it does not know where the entry point is.

[This github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1179) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6685) shows similar issues.

This is an example I've got from one of my apps running in SF:

```
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton(startup))
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, startup.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
```

In the above example, `startup` is an instance of a class that implements `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup` with following methods:

```
    void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app);
    IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);
```

PS: You don't use `.UseStartup<Startup>()` in the example above, but you could if there was one in the project.